# Django: ascii codec can't decode byte 0xe2

Tags: python, django

I have created a Django application with python 3.4 on windows platform. Now I am trying to host it on AWS Linux instance. First time I faced the following error

> Non-ASCII character '\xe2'

I resolved this issue by adding utf on each page.

> ## -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

Now I am facing the following error

> 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 18: ordinal not in
>   range(128)

Code:

```
class TaskTodo:

    @classmethod
    def validate_search(cls, form_data):

        try:

            search_url = 'https://www.foo.com/s-{search}/page-{page}'

            url = search_url.format(page=1, search=form_data['keywords'])
            url = url.encode('utf-8')

            r = requests.get(url)

            not_found_text = 'Sorry, but we didn’t find any results. Below you can find some tips to help you in your search.'

            if not_found_text in r.text.encode('utf-8'):
                return

            #after encoding its not working on localhost
            #'str' does not support the buffer interface

            if r.status_code == 200:
                content = r.text
                soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
                total = soup.find('span', {"class": 'count'}).text.replace('words', '').replace(',', '').strip()

                pages = 1
                last_page = soup.find('a', {"class": 'last follows'})

                if last_page:
                    href = last_page['href'].split('/')
                    pages = int(href[len(href) - 1].replace('somewords', '').strip())

        except Exception as ex:
            raise ex
```

I have searched and tried to implement encoding etc but doesn't work. I have completed the application and mostly functions are doing request to http, parsing html etc. Its really worrying for me to debug on production server and encode each function.

I am using Apache on production server and tried with both python version 2.7 and 3.5

Any idea how can I resolve this issue. Thanks

Comment: You need to show the [code that is producing the error](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: there might be a problem with your terminal. Is there a possibility to try in a different environment? I faced with that when there was locale problems on the server.

Comment: @Snobby no, that's not the problem

Comment: Please provide a full stacktrace and tell us why are you're doing `.encode('utf-8')`

Comment: There is a no error in log file. encode('utf-8') tried to resolve the issue.

Comment: @Snobby Different environment mean change OS? Sorry I am windows OS guy first time deploying the app on linux. :)

Comment: Where are you seeing the error? It should also be giving you an indication of which line through the error

Comment: I am looking into this file /var/log/apache2/error.log

Comment: Either remove the .encode(), or add .decode('utf-8') where the line you got the exception

Comment: @DuD. No, No :) There you should be no need to use `.decode()`

Comment: Get rid of by encoding the requests response r.text.encode('utf-8'). but don't know what is best solution.

Comment: @AskQuestion try setting your Apache log level to DEBUG to see if you get more info

Comment: @AskQuestion or add a file logger and log properly. Also, I suspect you're not showing us all the code.

Comment: yes one line I skipped and it causing the error. i thought its not important but now failed to run on local

Comment: @AskQuestion so there's no problem and we can close this question?

Comment: Update the code please check, If i removed encode from response it works on localhost but not on production server

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135222/discussion-between-alastair-mccormack-and-askquestion).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After working with the OP in a chatroom it was still unclear where the actual problem came from.

I noticed that the text `'Sorry, but we didn’t` contains a non-ascii `'RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK'`
Therefore, I recommended making `not_found_text` a Unicode by appending `u''` to the string value.

I also recommended removing removing all spurious `.encodes()` and `.decodes()`.